# How to set function keys as TouchBar default for Java applets

Tags: keyboard, touch-bar

I found [this resource](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207240) which outlines exactly what I want to do, however does not work for Java applets. Is there any way to display the function keys as default when using a Java applet, or any way to set key combination I can enter to lock the function keys on the TouchBar until I enter it again?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the list in System Preferences only accepts .app files, not .jar or .java. For files like Minecraft you can put the launcher in the list and it works for the game itself, but obviously this won’t work for standalone java apps.

Comment: I have the same question, did you ever find it out

Comment: @Jake unfortunately not, hoping that function will become available in a future software update.